# Robot Framework - customise log output

Tags: robotframework

I'm using Robot Framework to run some tests from SpiraTest.
At the end of the test, Robot FW logs the final statement this way:

> Test 1  |PASS|
>
> 1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed.

My problem is that the Regular Expression in Spiratest triggers the "0 failed" string in the 2nd row as if the whole test has failed, and this has higher priority with respect to the |PASS| statement in the row above.
For this reason, the test is marked as "failed", even if it passed.

Is there any way to mask the second row of the output?

Many thanks in advance,
gischio

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was in the Regex that triggers the Failed status.
I've asked the Spirateam support and I've been told it is enough to add

[0-9][1-]* failed

in the RegEx for Failed.